# jQuery/Svg : increment value "dur" when key is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, increment, keycode

I would like to increase the speed of my element `#Object` when I press a key.

The HTML code:

```
<path d="M 0,70 A 65,70 0 0,0 65,0 5,5 0 0,1 75,0 75,70 0 0,1 0,70Z" fill="#FF6600">
    <animateTransform id="object" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="360 0 0" to="0 0 0" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
</path>
```

The Script:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPressed, false);

function checkKeyPressed(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == "38") {
        var getTheSpeed = parseInt(document.getElementById("object").dur, 10);
        getTheSpeed = isNaN(getTheSpeed) ? 3 : getTheSpeed;
        getTheSpeed++;
        document.getElementById("object").dur = getTheSpeed;
    }
}
```

My problem is that `dur` doesn't only take a number value. The seconds "s" must be specified. So, I cannot actually use `isNaN` property :(

I'm a beginner in JavaScript ^^'
Anyone have a solution to run this script?
Ty <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the following lines

```
var getTheSpeed = parseInt(document.getElementById("object").getAttribute("dur").slice(0,-1), 10);
```

(this will remove the s from the current value of "dur" using `slice(0,-1)`)

and

```
document.getElementById("object").setAttribute("dur",String(getTheSpeed) + "s");
```

(this will set the new incremented value with an s added to it using string concatenation  `+ "s"`)

Check this out--hope it helps^^

```js
window.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPressed, false);

function checkKeyPressed(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == "38") {
        var getTheSpeed = parseInt(document.getElementById("object").getAttribute("dur").slice(0, -1), 10);
        getTheSpeed = isNaN(getTheSpeed) ? 3 : getTheSpeed;
        getTheSpeed++;
        document.getElementById("object").setAttribute("dur", String(getTheSpeed) + "s");
        alert(document.getElementById("object").getAttribute("dur"));
    }
}
```

```html
<path d="M 0,70 A 65,70 0 0,0 65,0 5,5 0 0,1 75,0 75,70 0 0,1 0,70Z" fill="#FF6600">
    <animateTransform id="object" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="360 0 0" to="0 0 0" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
</path>
```